# Having trouble casting string to list in racket

Tags: racket

I'm pretty new to racket and I'm having trouble with casting a string to a list. I'm working on making a basic boggle game for a class right now, and I keep getting this error from the following code :

car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: "aarhus" <--error

```
(define (word-is-in? a-word a-rand-list)
  ((cond
     [(string? a-word)(string->list a-word)]
     )
   (cond
    [(empty? a-word) #t] ;; Found all letters in a-word
    [(empty? a-rand-list) #f]
    [(is-in (car a-word) a-rand-list)
      (word-is-in? (cdr a-word)
                   (remove-item (car a-word) a-rand-list))
    ]
    [else #f] ;; first letter of a-word not in a-list

  )
 )
)
```

what this function is supposed to do is read in a word from a list of words (a-word) return #t IFF all the letters in a-word are in a-list. I think my problem is that a-word is being read in as a string. That is why I added in

```
(cond
   [(string? a-word)(string->list a-word)]
)
```

at the top of the function. I was hoping it would cast the string to a list, yet I am still getting this error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in here `[(is-in (car a-word) a-rand-list) ...]`.
`a-word` is still a `string`, hence you can not call `car` on it.

I suppose you have 2 separate conditionals to first "cast" the string into a list and in the second conditional use that list?

```
((cond
     [(string? a-word)(string->list a-word)]
     )
```

If that is what you want to do you should do `(set! a-word (string->list a-word))`. This is because `string->list` will return the string as a list, but won't assign it to `a-word`.

PS : In this case i would change the first conditional into a `when` statement.

Comment: Thank you! I think that did it for that function. One of my other functions is bugging out now, but I don't think it has anything to do with my previous problem.

Comment: Actually, I do have a question about this that I can't find online. When the string is set to a list, does it become a list of characters or a list of single letter strings?

Comment: Do the test ;) `(char? (car (string->list "abc")))` will return #t, which means it is a list of characters. However if you need a list of strings you can simply `map` it, then it becomes `(set! a-word (map string (string->list a-word)))`.

Comment: I actually wouldn't `set!` `a-word`; I'd just tail-call the function with the new parameter value.